# Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\Api\ApiAuthController::$auth

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, ionic-framework, angular5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWTWN.png)

Im new in Laravel i don't how to figure out the mistake
here is my laravel code:

```
    public function login(Request $request)
    {

      $gen_user = GenUser::where('username',$request->username)->where('confirmed',0)->first();
      if($gen_user){
        return response()->json(3);+6
      }

      if($this->auth->attempt($request->only('username','password'))){

        $gen_user = GenUser::join('gen_people','gen_users.gen_person_id','=','gen_people.id')
                            ->where('gen_users.id',\Auth::user()->id)
                            ->select(['gen_people.first_name','gen_people.middle_name','gen_people.last_name','gen_people.first_name','gen_users.id','gen_users.username','gen_users.confirmed'])
                            ->first();
   // dd($gen_user);
        $gen_user->name = $gen_user->first_name." ".$gen_user->middle_name." ".$gen_user->last_name;

        if($gen_user->confirmed == 1){
          return response()->json($gen_user);
        }elseif($gen_user->confirmed == 2){
          return response()->json(2);
        }else{
          return response()->json(3);
        }

      }else{
        return response()->json(false);
      }
    }
```

Can someone help me...thanks in advance...

Comment: It seems the property `$this->auth` does not exist. Did you copy this code from somewhere?

Comment: yes from previous project ..

Answer (score 0):

When you use `this` keyword you mean refer to exactly current class.but in your that controller there is not any `auth` method or property.

Create authentication(or if you use `passport` it make it automaticly) and migrate.
After that you can use

> Auth::attempt(['username'=>request('username'),'password'=>request('password')])